# Who are the different gods/ people in the cosmic from of Shri Krishna?

Tags: krishna, identification-request

In this [Image](https://images.app.goo.gl/vD5fHEFvwrM8UFhv8) there are many heads with all different faces some I can identify like Lord Shiva, Lord Ganesha. But others I can't.

So who are they?

[image]

Comment: You may start reading from here (https://www.gitasupersite.iitk.ac.in/srimad?htrskd=1&etsiva=1&&language=dv&field_chapter_value=11&field_nsutra_value=3) on, the BG Ch. 11, gives all the exact details of what's was seen. For interpolation purposes, one may assume that the Cosmic Form is the full Saguna Manifestation of the Par Brahman, with all the possible permutations and combinations of existence invariably contained within them and hence shown to Arjuna!

Comment: Right next to Krishna On the right hand side is Rama/Vishnu. Left most is Narsimha Bhagwan (there’s a face after that too but not counting that), next to Shivji is Brahmaji;  Right most is Agnideva, Next to him is Hanumanji. One of the two rishis is Parshurama.